# Upload file using trest client component with post method

Tags: talend

trying to upload file using trest client component with post method.
Able to upload file using postman post call.
Same thing is not working in Talend.
Getting 415 error.

[image: ERROR]

[image: header]

[image: basic setting]

trying to upload file using trest client component with post method.
Able to upload file using postman post call.
Same thing is not working in Talend.
Getting 415 error.

Comment: Please ... provide something!  Screenshots, code, anything!

Comment: added screenshot of error and header settings

Comment: What’s under basic settings?

Comment: updated with basic settings

Comment: Ok, last question, what’s the endpoint you’re calling? Full url.

Comment: means ? passing api url in URL section and service path in relative path.

Comment: As in the url and service itself. Is it an endpoint you guys have developed or a public service that even I can sign up for? I ask because I want to read the doco. You passing in an actual fully qualified filename is not how it’s usually done. It’s usually either free text as the body or base64 or binary or something like that. I want to check to see what the documentation says.

Comment: API documentation https://developer.adobe.com/analytics-apis/docs/2.0/guides/endpoints/bulk-data-insertion/endpoints/

Answer (score 0):

In tRestClient, Query parameters are string parameters, so even if you pass your file path in the "file" parameter, only the file path is passed as a string to your api and the actual file will not be uploaded.
You can upload a file using tFileFetch component, by checking "Upload file" in the advanced settings.
[image]